# Bitcoin-qt getnewaddress returns address starting with 2

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, testnet, p2sh

I am expecting it starts with '3' the the results below:

```
getnewaddress "" "p2sh-segwit"
2NFcKJTPZs1syYhwaBkXty6Vt6FEKxD3HTC
```

Is this because I am running on a private block chain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using testnet. Addresses starting with "M", "N", "2" and "tb1" are testnet addresses.